# Как скопировать html блока и очистить весь текст и адреса картинок?

Tags: jquery

Как можно скопировать `html` блока при клике на него и удалить весь текст и атрибут `src` у картинок? Если записывать в переменную так:

```
var a = $("k").html()
```

то копируется код внутри кликнутого блока, нужно копировать все вместе.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста пример блока

Comment: Пример не важен :-) Обычный див, в нем много дивов, абзацев, списков и картинок.

Comment: Ну тогда я не совсем понимаю задачу. Нужно вырезать готовый блок(верстку) без контента?

Comment: Да, все верно. Нужно получить только html, без текста и адресов картинок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPD:**

```js
$('div').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation(); //предотвращаем вспытие клика
  
  $(this).find('img').attr('src',''); //находим все картинки и удаляем src
  
 $(this).find('*').each(function(){ //в цикле пробегаем по всем дочерним элементам
   var nodes = this.childNodes; //формируем список узлов DOM
    
    for(var i=0; i<nodes.length;i++){ //проверяем, является ли узел текстовым и удаляем его
      if(nodes[i].nodeType === 3) {
          this.removeChild(nodes[i]);
      }
    }
  });
  
  var a = this.outerHTML; //заносим в переменную html блока, по которому был совершён клик
  alert(a);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="border: 1px solid red; padding: 10px;">

<div style="border: 1px solid blue; margin: 10px;">
<p>какой-то внутренний текст</p>
<img src="https://img3.goodfon.ru/original/1920x1080/d/f9/mercedes-benz-c63-amg-black-6319.jpg" alt="" width="300" />
<ul>
<li>Пункт 1</li>
<li>Пункт 2</li>
<li>Пункт 3</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div style="border: 1px solid blue; margin: 10px;">
<p>ещё какой-то внутренний текст</p>
<div>
  <p>
  <span>sdhgf stherytue erueryu</span>
  </p>
</div>
<img src="https://img3.goodfon.ru/original/1920x1080/d/f9/mercedes-benz-c63-amg-black-6319.jpg" alt="" width="300" />
<ul>
  <li>Point 1</li>
  <li>Point 2</li>
  <li>Point 3</li>
  <li><img src="https://img3.goodfon.ru/original/1920x1080/d/f9/mercedes-benz-c63-amg-black-6319.jpg" alt="" width="200" /></li>
  <li><p>wert wert <span>point 4</span></p><p>detail</p></li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
```

---

Просто нужно копировать html не того блока, по которому производится клик, а родительского:

```js
$('.inner').click(function(){
$('.inner img').attr('src','');
$('.inner p, .inner li').text('')
  var a = $(this).parent().html();
  alert(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="inner">
<p>какой-то внутренний текст</p>
<img src="https://img3.goodfon.ru/original/1920x1080/d/f9/mercedes-benz-c63-amg-black-6319.jpg" alt="" width="300" />
<ul>
<li>Пункт 1</li>
<li>Пункт 2</li>
<li>Пункт 3</li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: И заранее неизвестны классы родительского и дочернего блока, а также какие тэги внутри :-)

Comment: Теги внутри известны - Вы их сами перечислили: "много дивов, абзацев, списков и картинок". Насчёт родительского блока - можно использовать parent() - я обновил ответ.

Comment: Это я условно сказал, имелось ввиду и еще много других тэгов. Если бы я знал тэги, то почистить их от текста можно было бы без проблем. Я думал, есть какое-то решение, которое полностью удаляет текст, в независимости от тэгов.

Comment: @ВикторПавлов, да, такое решение есть - я добавил обновление в ответ.